# how to get the key value pair from a line in a file

Tags: php, laravel

**Hello. I have this line extracted from a file.**

```
2021-03-08 13:44:11,241  INFO [192.168.34.10] - response data ==> {
  "result": {
    "vResultCode": "N001000001100000",
    "orderInfos": {
      "orderInfo": [
        {
          "index": 0,
          "lastSuccessTxnType": "Authorize",
          "orderId": "9040000123",
          "orderStatus": "end",
          "properOrderInfo": {
            "cardExpire": "000",
            "startTxn": "60979460"
          },
          "serviceTypeCd": "card",
          "successDetailTxnType": "a",
          "transactionInfos": {
            "transactionInfo": [
              {
                "amount": "560",
                "command": "Authorize",
                "mstatus": "success",
                "properTransactionInfo": {
                  "cardTransactionType": "a",
                  "centerRequestDate": "20210308134240",
                  "centerResponseDate": "20210308134240",
                  "connectedCenterId": "jcn",
                  "gatewayRequestDate": "20210308134240",
                  "gatewayResponseDate": "20210308134240",
                  "loopback": "0",
                  "pending": "0",
                  "reqAcquirerCode": "05",
                  "reqAmount": "560",
                  "reqCardExpire": "*****",
                  "reqCardNumber": "411111*11",
                  "reqItemCode": "0990",
                  "reqJpoInformation": "10",
                  "reqSecurityCode": "000",
                  "reqWithCapture": "false",
                  "resActionCode": "000",
                  "resAuthCode": "000000",
                  "resCenterErrorCode": "   ",
                  "resReturnReferenceNumber": "012345678901",
                  "txnKind": "card"
                },
                "txnDatetime": "2021-03-08 13:42:40.285",
                "txnId": "60979460",
                "vResultCode": "A001000000000000"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "overMaxCountFlag": false,
    "searchCount": 1,
    "mstatus": "success",
    "serviceType": "search"
  }
}
```

How do i get the key value pairs from here? like i want to get the reqAmount which is '560' or the mstatus that is 'success' I'm using *php laravel* btw**

Comment: use json_decode on the response data, you have to extract only from the curly brace part.

Comment: Can you post your code here? Where do you get this data?

Comment: From where? Please share your attempts

Answer (score 0):

Extract data from your response start with curly braces and do it like below. your response contains json part and some info regarding IP and date. You can try it like this:

```
$responseData = '{
    "result": {
        "vResultCode": "N001000001100000",
        "orderInfos": {
            "orderInfo": [
                {
                    "index": 0,
                    "lastSuccessTxnType": "Authorize",
                    "orderId": "9040000123",
                    "orderStatus": "end",
                    "properOrderInfo": {
                        "cardExpire": "000",
                        "startTxn": "60979460"
                    },
                    "serviceTypeCd": "card",
                    "successDetailTxnType": "a",
                    "transactionInfos": {
                        "transactionInfo": [
                            {
                                "amount": "560",
                                "command": "Authorize",
                                "mstatus": "success",
                                "properTransactionInfo": {
                                    "cardTransactionType": "a",
                                    "centerRequestDate": "20210308134240",
                                    "centerResponseDate": "20210308134240",
                                    "connectedCenterId": "jcn",
                                    "gatewayRequestDate": "20210308134240",
                                    "gatewayResponseDate": "20210308134240",
                                    "loopback": "0",
                                    "pending": "0",
                                    "reqAcquirerCode": "05",
                                    "reqAmount": "560",
                                    "reqCardExpire": "*****",
                                    "reqCardNumber": "411111*11",
                                    "reqItemCode": "0990",
                                    "reqJpoInformation": "10",
                                    "reqSecurityCode": "000",
                                    "reqWithCapture": "false",
                                    "resActionCode": "000",
                                    "resAuthCode": "000000",
                                    "resCenterErrorCode": " ",
                                    "resReturnReferenceNumber": "012345678901",
                                    "txnKind": "card"
                                },
                                "txnDatetime": "2021-03-08 13:42:40.285",
                                "txnId": "60979460",
                                "vResultCode": "A001000000000000"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "overMaxCountFlag": false,
        "searchCount": 1,
        "mstatus": "success",
        "serviceType": "search"
    }
}';
$jsonRes = json_decode($responseData, true); //json string to array
$newRes = $jsonRes['result']['orderInfos']['orderInfo']; 
$count = count($newRes);
$j=0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo $newRes[$i]['transactionInfos']['transactionInfo'][$j]['amount'];
    $j++;
}
```

Output

`560`

We have extract your data and convert into array through `json_decode` function and get the amount through loop.
You can also get your output without loop, but there can be scenario where you will get multiple array objects.

Please replace `$i` and `$j` with `0`.

`echo $jsonRes['result']['orderInfos']['orderInfo'][0]['transactionInfos']['transactionInfo'][0]['amount'];`

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: tried this and it ways "count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"

also, what is the $new variable?

Answer (score 0):

Your extracted string basically contains some meta data (date, IP, etc.) followed by some JSON formatted data.

PHP has a built in function (`json_decode`) to handle converting JSON strings into PHP objects/arrays. So we just need to strip out the the excess data and then use the function on the remaining string:

```
$string = <<<EOT
2021-03-08 13:44:11,241  INFO [192.168.34.10] - response data ==> {"result":{"vResultCode":"N001000001100000","orderInfos":{"orderInfo":[{"index":0,"lastSuccessTxnType":"Authorize","orderId":"9040000123","orderStatus":"end","properOrderInfo":{"cardExpire":"000","startTxn":"60979460"},"serviceTypeCd":"card","successDetailTxnType":"a","transactionInfos":{"transactionInfo":[{"amount":"560","command":"Authorize","mstatus":"success","properTransactionInfo":{"cardTransactionType":"a","centerRequestDate":"20210308134240","centerResponseDate":"20210308134240","connectedCenterId":"jcn","gatewayRequestDate":"20210308134240","gatewayResponseDate":"20210308134240","loopback":"0","pending":"0","reqAcquirerCode":"05","reqAmount":"560","reqCardExpire":"*****","reqCardNumber":"411111*11","reqItemCode":"0990","reqJpoInformation":"10","reqSecurityCode":"000","reqWithCapture":"false","resActionCode":"000","resAuthCode":"000000","resCenterErrorCode":" ","resReturnReferenceNumber":"012345678901","txnKind":"card"},"txnDatetime":"2021-03-08 13:42:40.285","txnId":"60979460","vResultCode":"A001000000000000"}]}}]},"overMaxCountFlag":false,"searchCount":1,"mstatus":"success","serviceType":"search"}}
EOT;

echo(
    json_decode(preg_replace("/^.*==> ?/", "", $string))
        ->result
        ->orderInfos
        ->orderInfo[0]
        ->transactionInfos
        ->transactionInfo[0]
        ->properTransactionInfo
        ->reqAmount
    );
```

Output

```
560
```

---

**`preg_replace`**

Uses a regular expression (first parameter) to match against the string (third parameter) and replaces the matched data with the replacement value (second parameter).

```
/^.*==> ?/
/           : Pattern delimiter
 ^          : Matches the start of the string
  .*        : Matches any character 0 or more times
    ==>     : Matches literally
        ?   : Matches an optional space
         /  : Pattern delimiter
```

Comment: tried this and it says "Undefined property: stdClass::$orderInfos"

Comment: @soa The above works with the string provided. Perhaps if you could show how the string is derived?